# Naive Bayes classifier with intersecting/orthogonal feature sets?

Tags: statistics, classification, naivebayes

I'm faced with a classification problem that seems to lend itself to Naive Bayes Classifier (NBC). However, I have one problem: usually the NBC works by estimating the most likely Class c out of a set of classes C based on an observation x of a random variable X.

In my case I have multiple variables X1, X2 which might or might not share features. Variable X1 could have features (xa,xb,xc) and X2 might have (xc,xd) and another variable X3 might have (xe). Is it possible to construct one classifier, that allows me to classify X1,X2 and X3 simultaneously, in spite of the fact that the features are intersecting or even orthogonal?

The problem could be viewed from another point of view: for certain classes I am missing all data in certain features. Consider the following tables:

Classes = {C1,C2}.
Features = X = {X1,X2,X3},  X1={A,B}, X2={1,2}, X3={Y,N}

Class C1:

```
X1    X2    X3  #observations
 A     1     ?         50  
 A     2     ?         20  
 B     1     ?         20  
 B     2     ?         10
```

Class C2:

```
X1    X2    X3  #observations
 A     1     Y         20  
 A     1     N         0  
 A     2     Y         20  
 A     2     N         10  
 B     1     Y         10  
 B     1     N         20  
 B     1     Y         10  
 B     1     N         10
```

As you can see the feature X3 does not have any bearing on Class C1. No data is available for feature X3 in classifying class C1. Can I make a classifier that classifies X=(A,2,N) into both C1 and C2? How would I calculate the conditional probabilities for the missing data for X3 in class C1?

Comment: The different flavors of NBC assume that your features follow a certain distribution (e.g. Gaussian, see e.g. wikipedia). I'm not sure how much this will fit with your situation. Anyway, I'd suggest this is a question for [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/). Took a quick look and probably [this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108618/how-to-handle-unseen-features-in-a-naive-bayes-classifier) would help you.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Interesting site! I already looked at Laplace smoothing, but it can't seem to fill in my case. In effect my problem boils down to missing training data for specific combinations of classes and features. I'll update the description to match.